# Define function properties before function

Tags: javascript

I have an object `foo` that I want to call as a function `foo(...)`. I can do that like this:

```
foo = n => n * foo.factor;
foo.factor = 2;
foo(2) // returns 4
```

But for this to work I need to write the function (`n => n * foo.factor`) before other properties. How can I write it after? I want to do something like this:

```
foo = { factor: 2 }
// write function
foo(2) // returns 4
```

Comment: You normally don't define properties on a function, it looks like you want a `class` instead

Comment: @IrkenInvader ever heard of jquery?

Comment: @JonasW. in my perfect world I wouldn't normally use jquery either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a small utility:

```
 const functionize = (obj, fn) => Object.assign(fn, obj);
```

So one can do:

```
let foo = { factor: 2 };
foo = functionize(foo, n => n * foo.factor);
foo(2);
```

---

Or you just use a regular function:

```
foo.factor = 2;

function foo(n) { return foo.factor * n; }
```

---

> I wish there was a way to define my object as a function and then later change its body...

```
 const foo = (...args) => (foo.body || () => null)(...args);
 foo.factor = 2;
 foo.body = n => foo.factor * n;
 foo(2);
```

Comment: This is works. Thanks. But is this the only way? My object is a ```const``` so I don't want to reassign it

Comment: @diego there are thousand ways. However none of them is recommendable nor useful

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a ```const``` object ?

Comment: @diego no you can't rewrite `const` and you cant magically change an object into a function.

Comment: But a function is an object. I wish there was a way to define my object as a function and then later change its body...

Comment: @diego oh that is actually possible. But still dynamically changing functions is the worst thing you can do concerning performance and stability.

Comment: For this I don't care about performance. The code is for a math model and using the ```foo(...)``` notation is more legible. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it with a simple helper:

```
const annotate = (f, annotations) => {
    Object.assign(f, annotations);
    return f;
};
```

...which you'd use like this:

```
foo = annotate(n => n * foo.factor, {factor: 2});
foo(2); // returns 4
```

**But I wouldn't**. Instead, I'd create a function builder:

```
const makeFoo = factor => n => n * factor;
```

and then:

```
const foo = makeFoo(2);
foo(2); // returns 4
```

Live example:

```js
const makeFoo = factor => n => n * factor;

const foo2 = makeFoo(2);
console.log(foo2(2)); // returns 4

const foo4 = makeFoo(4);
console.log(foo4(2)); // returns 8
```